# $.ajax call in firefox

Tags: jquery, ajax, firefox

I am attempting to use $.ajax.  Based on this response I will show or hide some container.  The problem is that in Chrome the response comes back fine and the success callback works just fine.  However, in Firefox the response is coming back as undefined.  I attempted to set the datatype to json and then parse the json once the response comes back but that didn't work either. I just got an error saying that the data was incomplete and couldn't be parsed.

Here is the javascript:

```
var infoId = $("#infoId").val();

    $.ajax({
        type: "GET",
        url: "http://localhost/HartvilleServices.Enrollment/Participation",
        data: "userInformationId=" + infoId,
        processData: false
    })
        .error(function(x, s, e) {
            $("#thankYou-container").css("display", "none");
            $("#survey-container").css("display", "block");
        })
        .success(function (data) {
            $.each(data, function (key, val) {
                if (val.hasResponse == "False") {
                    $("#thankYou-container").css("display", "none");
                    $("#survey-container").css("display", "block");
                } else {
                    $("#thankYou-container").css("display", "block");
                    $("#survey-container").css("display", "none");
                }

            });
        });
```

Can anyone give me some insight?  I have never noticed this issue before.

Comment: Can you see the results coming back in Firebug? Is it the same in Chrome?

Comment: Yes I can and the results are coming back fine.  For instance, in FF if I remove the .hasResponse then I can see the json with the correct value

Comment: Try adding `dataType: 'json'` to the options. Chrome might detect the response and parse it while FF doesn't.

Comment: I agree with Felix.  I seem to remember having had the same issue before and it was caused by an incorrect content-type of the server response.  Chrome still recognized it as JSON, while FF didn't. Adding `dataType: 'json'` forced jQuery to treat it as JSON anyways.

Comment: " I attempted to set the datatype to json and then parse the json once the response comes back but that didn't work either. " From the question.

Comment: You don't have to parse the result if dataType is "JSON" because jQuery will automatically parse it for you.

Comment: I feel like the problem is in your data. Can you post the response data? Maybe your `val` is being treated as a string and not an object. Just curious to try `$.parseJSON(val).hasResponse`. Your conditional is based on the fact that `val` is indeed an object, not just the `data` being an object.

Comment: @devnull69 I've seen many cases where jQuery makes a mistake, especially in FireFox for some reason. From the jQuery docs: The type of data that you're expecting back from the server. If none is specified, jQuery will try to infer it based on the MIME type of the response (an XML MIME type will yield XML, in 1.4 JSON will yield a JavaScript object, in 1.4 script will execute the script, and anything else will be returned as a string). Keyword: TRY.

Comment: Setting the MIME type (Content-type) in the header of the response (server-side) to application/json could also help.